# Angular Bootstrap how to add pagination

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to know how can i add pagination im my angular app. The data is big so i want to show in pager like in first pager 30 array.

This is my html file

```
     <table class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
        <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>STATUS</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Patient Name</th>
             <th>Approved Amount</th>
             <th>Claimed Amount</th>
             <th>Company</th>
             <th>Submitted By</th>
             <th>Claim No</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>

      <tbody>

         <tr *ngFor="let x of data1 | filterBy: userFilter" (click)="openDeal(deletecontent, x)" >
           <td>
             <span class="text-success">{{x.status}}</span>
           </td>
           <td >
             <div style="text-align: left;">
              <img [src]="x.userPhoto || 'https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/user-image-png.png'" class="img-sm" alt="" style="text-align: left;">
              {{x.member_name}}
             </div>
           </td>
          <td style="text-align: left;">{{x.patient_name}}</td>
          <td>{{x.approved_value}}</td>
          <td>{{x.claimed_value}}</td>
          <td>                                      
            <span  class="text-success" >{{x.company_id}}</span>
          </td>
          <td>{{x.submitted_at || 'not-defined'}}</td>
          <td>{{x.claim_id}}</td>

        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

I am fetching data by http request

```
this.url = 'http://url.com/insurance_IgiGen/insurance-api/get_claims.php?offset=0&limit=10';

this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url,
{
params: {
policy_id: this.userFilter.policy_id     
 },

}).
subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
this.spinner.hide();

this.data1 = data.records;

});
```

The data is Too large to load need to show in pagination like it will load first. I have already add offset and limit in api. I think it will done by limit in api ? Because i need to load the first 30 array from api in first pager then in next pager 30. Because data is too big it will take 30min to load the all data from api thats why i add the limit .

Comment: I have built an easy to use table component in my Easy Angular library https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez here is a stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npn1p1 and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5

Comment: thanks but i think it will use pager after getting all data ?. I need to add pager by limit like it will load first 30 data by limit in api

Comment: You will need to modify your api as well if you want to implement server side pagination. What is your backend code written in?

Comment: @nash11 Thank i already add the limit function in api. mean if i pass offset 0 and limit 30 . it will show data by 0 to 30 . if ill add offset 31 to 60. it will show data from 31 to 60.

Answer (score 0):

Client Side Pagination Component:

```
<div class="card-list-footer">
  <i (click)="prevPage()"
  [ngClass]="{'card-pagination-icon-disabled': currentIndex === 0}" class="fa fa-chevron-left card-pagination-icon"></i>
  <i (click)="nextPage()"
  [ngClass]="{'card-pagination-icon-disabled': currentIndex >= (totalList.length - pageCount)}"
  class="fa fa-chevron-right card-pagination-icon card-pagination-icon--right"></i>
</div>
```

Client Side Pagination Component Logic:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagination',
  templateUrl: './pagination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagination.component.scss']
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit {
  private _totalPages: number;
  public totalList: Array<any> = [];

  @Input('list-items') set listItems(value) {
    if (value && value !== this.totalList) {
      this.totalList = value;
      this._totalPages  = value.length;
    }
  }

  public currentIndex = 0;

  @Input('page-count') pageCount = 5;
  @Output()  paginate = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  paginateCard() {
    this.paginate.emit(this.totalList.slice(this.currentIndex, this.currentIndex + this.pageCount));
  }

  prevPage() {
    if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.currentIndex -= this.pageCount;
    this.paginateCard();
  }

  nextPage() {
    if (this.currentIndex >= (this.totalList.length - this.pageCount)) {
      return;
    }
    this.currentIndex += this.pageCount;
    this.paginateCard();
  }

}
```

How to use pagination component in the table component:

```
 <table class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>STATUS</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Patient Name</th>
         <th>Approved Amount</th>
         <th>Claimed Amount</th>
         <th>Company</th>
         <th>Submitted By</th>
         <th>Claim No</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>

  <tbody>

     <tr *ngFor="let x of pagedData | filterBy: userFilter" (click)="openDeal(deletecontent, x)" >
       <td>
         <span class="text-success">{{x.status}}</span>
       </td>
       <td >
         <div style="text-align: left;">
          <img [src]="x.userPhoto || 'https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/user-image-png.png'" class="img-sm" alt="" style="text-align: left;">
          {{x.member_name}}
         </div>
       </td>
      <td style="text-align: left;">{{x.patient_name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.approved_value}}</td>
      <td>{{x.claimed_value}}</td>
      <td>                                      
        <span  class="text-success" >{{x.company_id}}</span>
      </td>
      <td>{{x.submitted_at || 'not-defined'}}</td>
      <td>{{x.claim_id}}</td>

    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <app-audit-log-pagination [list-items]="data1" [page-count]="5"
              (paginate)="setCurrentPageArr($event)"></app-audit-log-pagination>
```

Your table component logic:

```
public data1: any;
public pagedData: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.url = 'http://url.com/insurance_IgiGen/insurance-api/get_claims.php?offset=0&limit=10';

   this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url,
     {
      params: {
        policy_id: this.userFilter.policy_id
     },

   }).
    subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.spinner.hide();

      this.data1 = data.records;
      this.pagedData = data.records.slice(0,5);
    });
 }

 setCurrentPageArr(slicedArr: Array<any>) {
   this.pagedData = slicedArr;
 }
```